# How Async really works and How to use it properly with node.js (node-webkit)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, asynchronous, node-webkit

efor this problem i am using [Node-Webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/) (node.js) and [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async), loading a Windows App.

The reason of this question is to definitively answer:

> *What really means asynchronous execution in Javascript and Node.Js.*

***My personal code problem is at the end of the Question. "The Case".***

I am going to explain all about the problem i have directly with a schematic summary. (And I will be updating the info as you help me to understand it)

---

**The Concept (theory)**

Imagine a Primary Screen (JS, Html, css, ... Node.js frameworks) and a Background Procedure (JS execution every 10 min, JS internal checks, background Database Optimization, ...).

Whatever you do in Primary Screen wont affect background execution (except some important cases), and Background can change even the Screen if he needs to (screen timers, info about online web status, ...)

Then the behaviour is like:

> **Thread 1:** *Your actions inside the App framework.*    **Thread 2:** *Background App routines*

**Any action as they finish gives his output to screen, despite of the rest of the actions in async parallel**

---

**The Interpretation (For me)**

I think this is something that "Async" will handle without problems, as a parallel execution.

```
async.parallel([
function(){ ... },
function(){ ... }
], callback);      //optional callback
```

So the Thread 1 and Thread 2 can work together correctly while they do not affect the same code or instruction.
The Content will be changing while any threads request something of/to it.

---

**The Implementation (Reality)**
Code is not fully asynchronous during the execution, there are sync parts with common actions, that when they need calls the async codes.

> Sync: Startup with containers -> Async: load multiple content and do general stuff -> Sync: Do an action in the screen -> ...

---

**The Case**

So here it is my *not working properly* code:

```
win.on('loaded', function() {

 $( "#ContentProgram" ).load( "view/launcherWorkSpace.html", function() {
$("#bgLauncher").hide();
win.show();

async.parallel([
    function()   //**Background Process: Access to DB and return HTML content**
    {       
            var datacontent = new data.GetActiveData();  
        var exeSQL = new data.conn(datacontent);
            if(exeSQL.Res) 
            {
                var r = exeSQL.Content;
                if(r.Found)
                {
                    logSalon = new data.activeSData(r)
                    $('#RelativeInfo').empty();
                    $("#RelativeInfo").html("<h4 class='text-success'>Data found: <b>" + logData.getName + "</b></h4>");
                }
            }
    },
    function()  //**Foreground Process: See an effect on screen during load.**
    {
        $("#bgLauncher").fadeIn(400);
        $("#centralAccess").delay(500).animate({bottom:0},200);
    }
]);
});
});
```

As you can see, im not using "Callback()" because i dont need to (and it does the same).

I want to do the Foreground Process even if Background Process is not finished, but the result of the code is done at same time when both request has finished...

If i disconect the DB manually, first function takes 3 seconds until gives an exception (that i wont handle). Until then, both proccess will not output (show on screen) anything. (Foreground Process should be launched whatever happends to Background Process).

*Thanks and sorry for so much explanation for something that looks like trivial.*

---

**EDITED**

This start to be annoying... I tried without Async, just a javascript with callback like this:

```
            launchEffect(function () {
            var datacontent = new data.GetActiveData();

            var exeSQL = new data.conn(datacontent);

            if(exeSQL.Res) 
            {
                var r = exeSQL.Content;

                if(r.Found)
                {
                    logData = new data.activeData(r)
                    $('#RelativeInfo').empty();
                    $("#RelativeInfo").html("<h4 class='text-success'>Salón: <b>" + log.getName + "</b></h4>");
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
function launchEffect(callback)
{
  $("#bgLauncher").fadeIn(400);
    $("#centralAccess").delay(500).animate({bottom:0},200);
    callback();
}
```

Even with this... Jquery doesnt work until the callback answer...

Comment: since you're using async library. that parallel call, will execute all listed functions in parallel yes BUT, it will wait for all to return before handling the callback to you. In fact you're missing the async parallel final callback that handles the result or error once the 2 functions finish executing.

Comment: Also your 2 functions are sync declared, that is no callback you call. If you look at the async documentation you should see the callbacks are used and they need to, so you can signal when each function completes. In your case, first function goes in "sync" and will wait to finish. You're still dealing with one event loop. If you want to keep this w/o callbacks, move the animation to be first since that executes and finishes then your DB call happens.

Comment: also, Javascript is NOT multithreaded, especially on browser side, except when you programmatically use web workers etc.

Comment: well, this is an example and it works, but as you say, all together at the end. But in real situations, an api that runs every 10 min in background, without stop your actual action, should be coded somehow like asynchronous. (node.js can execute multithreaded operations, and you call it with javascript) But i do not know how to do it.

Comment: use setTimeout() to schedule execution. Also if you do this from browser, heh there are hacks. call it via ajax.get inside a setTimeout function. Im successfully using async.parallel with 3 callbacks to call 3 APIs (amazon S3, google analytics and my own). it DOES work all in parallel, but they are calling out on an IO implementation and they use a callback approach. if you don't use callbacks, you will make your code 100% sync and then first function that goes into, will block the execution of the rest until done :)

Comment: async.parallel does not run the functions in parallel, the method name  is very misleading

Answer (score 1):

`node-webkit` let's you run code written like code for node.js, but is ultimately just a shim running in WebKit's Javascript runtime and only has one thread, which means that most 'asynchronous' code will still block the execution of any other code.

If you were running node.js itself, you'd see different behavior because it can do genuinely asynchronous threading behind the scenes. If you want more threads, you'll need to supply them in your host app.

Comment: Interesting, i have to check if that is true, I think i read about the similar behaviour between node.js and node-webkit including multithreading... Thank you anyway :D

Comment: async promises have always been single threaded in all implementations I'm aware of (nwjs, electron, nodejs, chrome) unlike C#/Java. They create microtasks which are executed as part of the event loop if they are signaled. So calls don't "block" (they return immediately) and they don't use a thread pool either (native apis synchronize back to the single thread for all javascript execution). The only way to create multiple threads of execution is via web workers (like webview) or new nwjs/electron windows which spawn an entirely new os process and have their own javascript context.